# Transferring data between different components through a map loop

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to switch from one component to another, and the second component needs to use one item from the array of the first component

The problem is that the second component always goes through the entire array up to the last element and displays only it, but I want to go through the index in onclick

[image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mXRzx.png)
[image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cl8OM.png)

this is the component of the cards

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { Button } from "react-bootstrap";
import { Card } from "react-bootstrap";
import { useSelector } from "react-redux";
import ShowDetails from "./ShowDetails";

export default function Electronic() {
  const electronics = useSelector((state) => state.productReducer);
  const [modalShow, setModalShow] = useState(false);

  //debugger
  return (
    <>
      <center dir="rtl">
        <br></br>
        <br></br>
        <br></br>
        <br></br>
        {electronics.map((item) => (
          <>
            <Card
              style={{
                width: "18rem",
                display: "inline-block",
                backgroundColor: "white",
                textAlign: "center",
                borderColor: "#fade0f",
                margin: 5,
              }}
            >
              <Card.Img
                variant="top"
                src={item.product_image}
                style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }}
              />
              <Card.Body>
                <Card.Title dir="rtl">{item.name}</Card.Title>
                <Button
                  style={{ backgroundColor: "#fade0f", borderColor: "#fade0f", color: "black" }}
                  variant="primary"
                  onClick={() => setModalShow(true)}
                >
                  פרטים
                </Button>
              </Card.Body>
              <ShowDetails
                products={item}
                show={modalShow}
                onHide={() => setModalShow(false)}
              ></ShowDetails>
            </Card>
          </>
        ))}
        <br></br>
        <br></br>
        <br></br>
        <br></br>
      </center>
    </>
  );
}
```

this is the model to show the details:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { Image } from "react-bootstrap";
import Button from "react-bootstrap/Button";
import Modal from "react-bootstrap/Modal";

export default function ShowDetails(props) {
  const [amount, setAmount] = useState(1);
  return (
    <>
      <Modal
        {...props}
        size="sm"
        aria-labelledby="contained-modal-title-vcenter"
        centered
        style={{ textAlign: "center" }}
        animation={true}
      >
        <Modal.Header closeButton></Modal.Header>

        <Modal.Body dir="rtl">
          <Image
            variant="top"
            src={props.products.product_image}
            style={{ width: 200, height: 200 }}
          />
          <Modal.Title id="contained-modal-title-vcenter" style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
            {props.products.name}
          </Modal.Title>
          <h5>{props.products.description}</h5>
          <h4>{props.products.price * amount} ₪</h4>

          <Button
            style={{ backgroundColor: "#fade0f", borderColor: "#fade0f", color: "black" }}
            onClick={() => {
              setAmount(Math.max(1, amount - 1));
            }}
          >
            -
          </Button>
          <h4 style={{ display: "inline-block", margin: 10 }}>{amount}</h4>
          <Button
            style={{ backgroundColor: "#fade0f", borderColor: "#fade0f", color: "black" }}
            onClick={() => {
              setAmount(Math.min(props.products.qty, amount + 1));
            }}
          >
            +
          </Button>
          <br></br>
          <br></br>
          <Button
            style={{
              backgroundColor: "#fade0f",
              borderColor: "#fade0f",
              color: "black",
              width: 200,
            }}
            onClick={() => {
              setAmount(1);
            }}
          >
            הוספה לסל
          </Button>
        </Modal.Body>
      </Modal>
    </>
  );
}
```

I expected it to show me the image of the USB, and finally it shows me the speakers for the computer, which is the last member of the array.
How can I fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can simply create a hook for the selected product

```
const [selectedProduct, setSelectedProduct] = useState({});
```

then when you click on one product you open the modal and also you store it in `selectedProduct` :

```
<Button
 style={{ backgroundColor: "#fade0f", borderColor: "#fade0f", color: "black" }}
 variant="primary"
 onClick={() => {
  setModalShow(true);
  setSelectedProduct(item)
 }}
>
פרטים
</Button>
```

now you don't need to pass all the products to the model (if you don't need them) but only the selected one and **make the ShowDetails `component` outside the `map` function**:

```
<ShowDetails
  product={selectedProduct}
  products={electronics} // <-- if you need them
  show={modalShow}
  onHide={() => setModalShow(false)}
></ShowDetails>
```